# Texture to Paint object in Android?

Tags: android, view

I am using the code at http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/comment-page-1/#comment-14326 for building custom view.

I wanted to display the image in place of drawing the hand through code. I have tried setting the texture for the hand but have not got any success.

Can anyone let me know how can I set the image in place of hand?

Comment: I have managed to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to apply texture to paint object with the help of BitmapShader. The example above applies texture to the rim and I applied the same logic to apply texture to hand. It works.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with a BitmapShader:

```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.images);
  fillBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
  mPaint.setShader(fillBMPshader);
```